# MIcrosoft Visual Studio/Silverlight beginner's question

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I'm getting the following message - "The name 'wc_OpenReadCompleted' does not exist in the current context"

Am I missing an important step in creating the request?

Here's my code:

```
private void buttonSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string myUrl = "http://www.url.net/mycode.php?name=" + textBoxFirstName.Text;
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenReadCompleted);
    wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(myUrl));
}
```

Comment: it seems that wc_OpenReadCompleted method does not exist in your code

Answer (score 2):

wc_OpenReadCompleted is the name of the eventhandler for the OpenReadCompleted event. It seems you have not defined it yet. Add it to your code like this:

```
void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

By the way, as you are typing the code that will attach your eventhandler, after you have typed the '+=', you get promted to press TAB. If you do so, Visual Studio will create the handler for you.